# zeros and pole of a product of analytic functions in $p$-adic setting

Tags: complex-analysis, p-adic-number-theory, analytic-functions

Let $p$ be a prime number, $\mathbb C_p$ be the completion of an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$. One denotes $|.|_p$ the norm of $\mathbb C_p$ normalized by $|p|_p=1/p$. Consider a sequence $(f_n)_n$ of power series defined on $\mathcal D=\{z\in\mathbb C_p\mid[z|_p<1\}$. One assumes that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(z)=1$ for all $z\in\mathcal D$. Can one assert that if $z_0\in\mathcal D$ is a zero (resp a pole) of $F:=\prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n$ then there exist $n_1\in\mathbb N_0$ such that $z_0$ is a zero (resp pole) of $f_{n_1}$.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: $p$ adic analysis is kind of weird as the usual exponential and logarithmic functions have to be modified and are weirder than the complex ones, so would look in a book on the subject for exactly what you need - there are good books by Koblitz and by Robert and some online notes by A. Baker https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~ajb/course-notes.html

Comment: You haven’t said where the coefficients of the $f_n$ lie. In $\Bbb C_p$, I suppose? Nor have you said what kind of convergence “$\lim_nf_n(z)=1$” involves. It can matter.

Comment: Yes, coefficients of $f_n$ are in $\mathbb C_p$.